# c#: Dictionary TryGetValue creating instance instead of getting reference

Tags: c#, dictionary, reference, out, trygetvalue

I'm a total noob with c#, and cannot figure out why the same method works in different ways. I'm making a simple spreadsheet application, and am using a Dictionary of cells, where the key is a string name and the value is a Cell object:

```
public struct Cell
{
    private string Name { get; }
    public Object Content { get; set; }

    public Cell(string n, Object o)
    {
        Name = n;
        Content = o;
    }
}
```

Now, I'll need to be able to easily add/change the contents of the cell, so I've been doing this:

```
Dictionary<string, Cell> cells = new Dictionary<string, Cell>();

//  Assign new cell to 5.0 & print
cells.Add("a1", new Cell("a1", 5.0));
Console.WriteLine(cells["a1"].Content);     //  Writes 5

//  Assign cell to new content & print
cells.TryGetValue("a1", out Cell value);
value.Content = 10.0;
Console.WriteLine(cells["a1"].Content);     //  Writes 5
Console.ReadKey();
```

Of course, the dictionary *creates* the new cell just fine, but when I use TryGetValue, the new content for the cell doesn't make it to the actual object I'm trying to get. I was expecting the second print to be 10. In debug, it seems like it instantiates a new Cell instead of getting the reference of the cell at hand.

I've used a Dictionary before, and I've used TryGetValue to change properties of the existing object. So here's two questions: What am I doing wrong in this case, and what factors determine if the method returns a reference or not?

Comment: You defined Cell as a struct.

Comment: [structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs) are value types. So you will retrieve a copy instead of the reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cell` is a `struct`. It is not recommended that you use a `struct` for objects that can be modified. I think you just found out why.

When `TryGetValue` returns the `struct`, it copies it into a `value`, which is a different `struct` than the one in the `Dictionary`.

Imagine if you replaced `struct` by `int` - another value type - would you expect assigning to the `int` from `TryGetValue` to change the `Dictionary` entry `int`?

If other constraints require you use a `struct`, you will need to update the `cells` `Dictionary` with the new `struct`, just as you would with any other value type:

```
Dictionary<string, Cell> cells = new Dictionary<string, Cell>();

//  Assign new cell to 5.0 & print
cells.Add("a1", new Cell("a1", 5.0));
Console.WriteLine(cells["a1"].Content);     //  Writes 5

//  Assign cell to new content & print
cells.TryGetValue("a1", out Cell value);
value.Content = 10.0;
cells["a1"] = value;  // update cells Dictionary
Console.WriteLine(cells["a1"].Content);     //  Writes 5
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Perfect, when I replaced 'struct' with 'class', it met my expectations. I guess the real problem here is that, per my professor's specifications, Cell is to be a struct. I suppose I could change the Dictionary to be <string, Object> (where Object is the cell's contents), but wouldn't that just eliminate the need for a Cell struct in the first place? Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `struct Cell` into a `class Cell`.

That's because `struct` is a value type and it's content can't be changed by reference.
If you want to go in detail, you can read about difference of value and reference types [here](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).